# How to source setup.bash in a ROS2 Dockerfile?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that sourcing setup.bash in a ros2 dockerfile is not that easy.  In particular,

`RUN bash -c "source /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.bash \ &&  echo ${AMENT_PREFIX_PATH}"`

does not print anything although AMENT_PREFX_PATH got a value from setup.bash.  I have to use the `RUN [.., ..]` syntax.  Is there an easier way to do so?

```
FROM ros:eloquent 

#this one does not work    
RUN bash -c "source /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.bash \
        &&  echo ${AMENT_PREFIX_PATH}"

#this one works, printing /opt/ros/eloquent
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.bash &&  echo ${AMENT_PREFIX_PATH}"]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370439/how-to-source-setup.bash-in-a-ros2-dockerfile?/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2021-01-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, a simple solution that works for me is

```
RUN . /opt/ros/${ROS_DISTRO}/setup.sh && other_commands
```

That is, use "." instead of "source", and use "setup.sh" instead of "setup.bash".

---

Originally posted by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) with karma: 186 on 2021-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4